# how to force alert Yes No when Bluetooth Activated?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, dialog, alert

I'm sure you all know that if you run the below code under any android.
It will enable your Bluetooth. But first, it will show you an alert showing a dialog Yes/No.

```
Intent turnOn = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
         startActivityForResult(turnOn, 0);
```

My question is quite simple.
How to force Yes selection on that dialog?

My purpose is to programatically force enabling the bluetooth, and any other alert Yes/No.
So the user no need to see Yes/No. They will use Yes only. no dialog.

Please share a bit of guide. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to enable BluetoothAdapter ([more info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html)) like this:

```
BluetoothAdapter mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
mAdapter.enable()
```

It requires the `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` permission

Comment: if i have another dialog... would it be possible to force the yes/no selection?